# error on boxcox transformation response variable must be positive

Tags: r, transformation

I have tried, log, sqrt root and arcsine transformation on my data and nothing worked.
I tried to use boxcox and I got the error response variable must be positive

```
md<-lm(Score1~Location1+Site1+Trial1+Stage1)

summary(md)

plot(md, which = 1)

bc<-boxcox(md, plotit = T, lambda = seq(0.5,1.5, by =0.1))
```

This is what I ran on R and I got the error message

[image]

Any idea on how I can fix my code?

Comment: We would not be able to help you without a fully reproducible example.

Comment: Can you please post your data sample as text, rather than as an image?  Images are unsearchable and inaccessible to screen readers.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The [Box-Cox transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_transform) is defined as `BC(y) = (y^lambda - 1)/lambda` (and as `log(y)` for `lambda==0`). This transformation is not generally well-defined for negative `y` values (because it requires raising negative values to a power, which generates complex values in most cases).

The `car` package provides similar transformations that allow negative input, specifically the Yeo-Johnson transformation (see Wikipedia link above) and an adjusted version of the Box-Cox transformation; these are available via `car::yjPower()` and `car::bcnPower()` respectively (see the [documentation](https://rdrr.io/cran/car/man/bcPower.html) for more details).

(Now that you know the names of some alternatives, you can also search for other R functions/packages that provide them.)